# Найти дату в строке-периоде

Tags: perl

Здравствуйте!
Есть, например, `$period = "12.10.2010-15.10.2011"` и есть `$date = "14.03.2011"`.
Так как мне проверить есть ли `$date` в `$period`?
Просьба не предлагать из периода делать массив, куда заносить все промежуточные его даты.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub cmp_date {
    my ($d1, $m1, $y1) = split /\./, shift;
    my ($d2, $m2, $y2) = split /\./, shift;
    if ($y1 > $y2) {
        return 1;
    } elsif ($y1 < $y2) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        if ($m1 > $m2) { return 1; }
        elsif ($m1 < $m2) { return -1; }
        else {
            if ($d1 > $d2) { return 1; }
            elsif ($d1 < $d2) { return -1; }
            else { return 0; }
        }
    }
}

my $d = '14.03.2012';
my $p = "12.10.2010-15.10.2011";
my ($d1, $d2) = split /-/, $p;
if (cmp_date($d, $d1) > 0 and cmp_date($d, $d2) < 0) {
    say "OK";
} else {
    say "NO";
}
```

Можно использовать `POSIX::strptime` или `DateTime::Format::strptime`, но мне показалось, что быстрее написать самому.

Comment: Работает! Спасибо Вам!! )

Comment: @AIex, обратите внимание, тут если дата совпадает с одним из концов периода будет `NO`. Если надо не так, просто замените `>0` на `>=0`

Comment: Ок! И соответственно <0 на <=0

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub ndate {
 join '', reverse split /\./, shift;
}

my $d = '14.03.2012';
my $p = "12.10.2010-15.10.2012";
my ($d1, $d2) = map {ndate $_} split /-/, $p;
if( ndate($d) <= $d2 and ndate($d) >= $d1 ) {
 print "Yes";
} else {
 print "No";
}
```

Функция `ndate` превращает дату из формата DD.MM.YYYY в число YYYYMMDD. После чего числа можно сравнивать обычным способом на больше-меньше.